# How to canonicalize home directory?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to canonicalize a simple path containing the home directory `~` in Rust:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
  let path_str = "~"; // fails
  // let path_str = ".."; // works
  let path_buf = PathBuf::from(path_str);
  let canon = path_buf.canonicalize().unwrap();
  println!("{:?}", canon);
}
```

In my actual program, the `~` path comes from user input. This program fails on the `.canonicalize().unwrap()`, giving
`Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }`.

Is it a bug or a feature that Rust fails to canonicalize the `~`?
What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I would say that this is for cross-compatibility reasons, as IIRC `~` is Unix specific, so I feel that you should use a Unix specific mechanism to expand it. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267608/expand-tilde-in-rust-path-idiomatically) can help?

Comment: All the `fs` stuff is OS-specific to begin with, right? It has different logic for Windows vs Unix, so I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that tilde expansion is a *shell* feature, and has nothing to do with the underlying file system. You are under no obligation to support it. `..`, on the other hand, *is* an actual file system entry (where available), not a shell shortcut.