# How to mutate the underlying String of a PathBuf?

Tags: rust

I want a function that mutates the underlying `String` of a `PathBuf` object, but all I could achieve now is creation of a new object instead.

```rust
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn expanduser(path: &mut PathBuf) -> PathBuf {
    return PathBuf::from(
        &path
            .to_str()
            .unwrap()
            .replace("~", PathBuf::home().to_str().unwrap()),
    );
}
```

Comment: Also if you are just looking to replace references to "~", you might be better solved with the canonicalize method: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#method.canonicalize https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html function

Comment: @John Kugelman 
I see. But can't we go back and forth between them? even if there are caveats? Do you reckon that it would be too much work, that creation of a new object would be cheaper (computationally)?

Comment: @user1937198 `.canonicalize()` doesn't handle `~`, it only normalizes away `.`, `..`, and symlinks, you need [a crate](https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=home%20dir) to deal with `~`

Comment: @user1937198 I hate that function, cause if the path I'm canonicalizing doesn't exist, it throws an error instead of gracefully doing what it should do. No one asked it to check existence.

Comment: You can go back and forth between them, yes. That's what you're already doing: convert path to string (which could fail), manipulate string, convert back. What you can't do is use string functions to manipulate the path *in place*.

Comment: I think you might be looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306906/11423104

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand tilde in Rust Path idiomatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54267608/expand-tilde-in-rust-path-idiomatically)

Comment: @Jmb the tilde affair is only coincidental to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PathBuf` wraps an `OsString`, not a `String`. They are much different types - `String` contains a UTF-8 string while `OsString` depends on the platform: arbitrary bytes for Unix and potentially-malformed UTF-16 on Windows.

You can use `into_os_string` to convert a `PathBuf` to an `OsString`, and `From` for the reverse.

If you are just trying to replace `~` with the home path, your best bet is to check if the first component (via the components method) is a Normal component containing "~" and join the rest of the components to the home path if so. There's crates that do this for you.

> I hate that function, cause if the path I'm canonicalizing doesn't exist, it throws an error instead of gracefully doing what it should do. No one asked it to check existence.

You're likely misunderstanding the function. `canonicalize` resolves symlinks, so of course it won't work if the path doesn't exist. Also worth mentioning is that `foo/bar/../baz` is NOT necessarily the same as `foo/baz`, if `foo/bar` is a symlink.