# No method named `save` found for unit type `()` in the current scope

Tags: rust

I want to merge two images. I'm using `image::imageops::overlay` from the image crate:

```
use image::imageops::overlay;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path1 = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-merge/image1.png");
    let path2 = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-merge/image2.png");
    let mut img1 = image::open(&path1).unwrap().clone();
    let mut img2 = image::open(&path2).unwrap().clone();
    let output = overlay(&mut img1, &mut img2, 0, 0);
    let save_path = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-crop/merged.png");
    output.save(save_path).unwrap();
}
```

After hitting `cargo run`, I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `save` found for unit type `()` in the current scope
--> src/main.rs:11:12
   |
11 |     output.save(save_path).unwrap();
   |            ^^^^ method not found in `()`
```

I think the compiler is saying `image::imageops::overlay` doesn't have the method `save()`? If so, what should I use instead?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27cb003261e5c11445bd1d5029dae8ee)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`image::imageops::overlay`](https://docs.rs/image/latest/image/imageops/fn.overlay.html) mutates the image passed as the first argument, overlaying the second image on it, and returns `()`. You need to call `.save()` on `img1` since that image now has `img2` overlayed on it. Also, you don't need to pass a mutable reference to `img2` to `overlay` and the `.clone()` calls are unnecessary.

```rust
use image::imageops::overlay;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path1 = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-crop/image1.png");
    let path2 = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-crop/image2.png");
    let mut img1 = image::open(&path1).unwrap();
    let img2 = image::open(&path2).unwrap();
    overlay(&mut img1, &img2, 0, 0);
    let save_path = Path::new("~/Desktop/to-crop/merged.png");
    img1.save(save_path).unwrap();
}
```

Also, `~` will not be expanded by Rust automatically, so you need to pass the full path to the images. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54267608).

---

Creating a `Path` is also unnecessary since both the functions accept `P: AsRef<Path>`, which means you can pass `&str` directly:

```
use image::imageops::overlay;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let path1 = "~/Desktop/to-crop/image1.png";
    let path2 = "~/Desktop/to-crop/image2.png";
    let mut img1 = image::open(&path1).unwrap();
    let img2 = image::open(&path2).unwrap();
    overlay(&mut img1, &img2, 0, 0);
    let save_path = "~/Desktop/to-crop/merged.png";
    img1.save(save_path).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I think I don't need `clone()`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've updated my answer to include that too.

Comment: You can even pass the path directly as a string to `image::open` and `.save()` since they accept any `T: AsRef<Path>`.

Comment: "You can even pass the path directly as a string ..." So all the `Path::new`s are unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, I've added another version of the code with these changes.